# How to apply a hover effect while inside a click popup jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, click

I have a container div that is hidden initially until a click event occurs. The div contains an image. I want to apply a hover effect over that image however, I can't get the hover to work since it is being overridden by the click event. Below is my code.

```
<div class='comment-click'>
    <div class="comment-product">
        <img class="checkered-shirt" src="img/checkered.jpg" />
        <div class="comment-hover-popup">
            <img class="popup-pic" src="img/Calvin_pic.png" />
            <h2 class="hover-title">Nautica</h2>
            <p class="description">Nautica Men's Hyannis Shoe</p>
            <input class="buy" id="buy" type="submit" value="Buy" />
            <p class="price">$55</p>
            <p class="hover-comment-command">Comment (2)</p>
            <img class="plus-icon" src="img/plus-icon.png" />
            <img class="check-icon" src="img/check-icon.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>J.Crew</h1>
    <p class="product-description">J.Crew Plaid Button Down Shirt</p>
    <img class="comment-x" src="img/x.png" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="comment-one">
                <img src="img/Calvin_pic.png" />
                <p class="product-commenter">Paul Mickan </p>
                <p class="product-comment">Love this shirt #hipster</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="comment-two">
                <img src="img/Calvin_pic.png" />
                <p class="product-commenter">Calvin Hemington </p>
                <input class="product-comment" type="text" name="Add a comment..." onfocus="if (this.value=='Add a comment...') this.value = ''" value="Add a comment..." /></a>
            <input class="comment-post" type="submit" value="Post" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.hover-comment-command').click(function () {
    $('.comment-click').fadeIn();
    $('.comment-hover-popup').hide();
});

$('.comment-x').click(function () {
    $(".comment-click").fadeOut();
});

$(".checkered-shirt").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.comment-hover-popup').fadeIn(300);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.comment-hover-popup').hide();
});
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `div` tag for `.comment-click`, making it unclear what's happening here. It appears that clicking on an element makes its parent appear, which seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).siblings()` instead of `$(this).find()` in your `hover()` function

```
$(".checkered-shirt").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.comment-hover-popup').fadeIn(300);
}, function () {
    $(this).siblings('.comment-hover-popup').hide();
});
```

`find()` is for decendants of the matched element

`siblings()` is for, well, siblings of the matched element

[See the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Except the hover only works if I place my mouse over the image and leave it there. Whenever I move around the mouse within the hover area the hover effect pulsates on and off. Have any ideas as to why?

Comment: @CalvinHemington - I can't reproduce that behavior with the code.  What version of jQuery are you using and what browser are you using?